# Command line argument to get monitor resolution only returns one monitor

Tags: batch-file, cmd, screen-resolution

I have a Windows 7 laptop connected to two extra monitors. In order to extend the taskbar to these additional monitors (Win7 does not natively have this ability, unlike Win10) I use a program called `DualMonitor.exe`.

My problem is that when I disconnect the laptop from these extra monitors, the programs managed by `DualMonitor` become hidden. To remedy this, I made a simple batch file to restart `explorer` and `DualMonitor`.

```
@echo off

taskkill /f /im dualmonitor.exe
ping localhost -n 1 > nul

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
ping localhost -n 3 > nul

echo.
echo restarting explorer

start explorer.exe
ping localhost -n 6 > nul

echo restarting dual monitor
start "" "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Dual Monitor\DualMonitor.exe"
```

The batch above works fine, but I wanted to adjust this so that it ONLY opens `DualMonitor` in the case that extra monitors are connected. I did some research and found these commands which can be modified to **count the number of additional monitors connected to the laptop**:

```
wmic desktopmonitor  get screenwidth, screenheight

wmic path Win32_VideoController  get CurrentHorizontalResolution, CurrentVerticalResolution
```

...but for me both of **these only return the resolution for the laptop's monitor** despite being connected to two additional monitors. I don't have admin rights to this machine so I am unable to utilize `dxdiag` in my solution.

---

**End Result**

```
@echo off

taskkill /f /im dualmonitor.exe
ping localhost -n 1 > nul

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
ping localhost -n 3 > nul

echo.
echo restarting explorer

start explorer.exe
ping localhost -n 3 > nul

for /F %%M in ('
    wmic path Win32_PnPEntity where "Service='monitor' and Status='OK'" get DeviceID /VALUE ^
        ^| find /C "="
') do set count=%%M

if %count% GTR 1 (
    echo restarting dual monitor.
    start "" "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Dual Monitor\DualMonitor.exe"
    ping localhost -n 4 > nul
)

echo.
echo all done.
ping localhost -n 2 > nul
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine the number of connected monitors you could use the following code:

```cmd
for /F %%M in ('
    wmic path Win32_PnPEntity where "Service='monitor' and Status='OK'" get DeviceID /VALUE ^
        ^| find /C "="
') do echo There are %%M monitors.
```

Refer to the article [Win32_PnPEntity class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394353(v=vs.85).aspx) for the WMI class `Win32_PnPEntity`.

Answer (score 0):

use `wmic` like you did, but select one property only and count the occurences:

```
for /f %%a in ('wmic desktopmonitor get DeviceID /value ^| find /c "="') do set "monitors=%%a"
echo there are %monitors% monitors.
```

Comment: unfortunately it returns "there are 1 monitors" :(

Comment: that's strange. Both `desktopmonitor` and `win32_videocontroller` list all connected monitors on my system.

Comment: I believe this depends on the settings of multiple displays: duplicate, extend, desktop on #...

Comment: for posterity, I had it set to extend with one of the additional monitors being the "main" one with the desktop